# How to update CloudWatch Agent version on Windows Instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-systems-manager

Let's say that the CloudWatch Agent installed on Windows Server was version X.0. After few months, there was an update, and the latest available version of CloudWatch Agent was X.1. So, how can I proceed with updating the already installed CloudWatch Agent version on Windows Server?

In the user guide, I am able to find ways to 'Download and Configure the CloudWatch Agent' and other related processes but not able to find ways to update the CloudWatch Agent version.

Any prompt support in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-install using **AWS Systems Manager**, for that Systems Manager has to be installed already and you need to add these **I AM roles** if not there already
*AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore*, CloudWatchAgentServerPolicy.

**Download the CloudWatch agent package**
Systems Manager Run Command enables you to manage the configuration of your instances. You specify a Systems Manager document, specify parameters, and execute the command on one or more instances. SSM Agent on the instance processes the command and configures the instance as specified.

To download the CloudWatch agent using Run Command:

1. Open the Systems Manager console at
   https://console.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/.
2. In the navigation pane, choose **Run Command**.
   -or-
   If the AWS Systems Manager home page opens, scroll down and choose
   **Explore Run Command.**
3. Choose Run command.
4. In the Command document list, choose **AWS-ConfigureAWSPackage**.
5. In the **Targets** area, choose the instance on which to install the
   CloudWatch agent. If you do not see a specific instance, it might not be configured for Run Command. For more information, see Setting Up AWS Systems Manager for Hybrid Environments in the *AWS Systems Manager User Guide*.
6. In the **Action** list, choose **Install**.
7. In the Name box, enter *AmazonCloudWatchAgent*.
8. Keep Version set to latest to install the latest version of the agent.
9. Choose **Run**.
10. Optionally, in the Targets and outputs areas, select the button next to an instance name and choose View output. Systems Manager should show that the agent was successfully installed.

As below it does uninstall and reinstall.
[image]

Reference: [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/install-CloudWatch-Agent-on-EC2-Instance-fleet.html)